# How to place a figure in Latex while the [htbp] doesnt work?

Tags: floats, positioning

I insert a figure in to my document using code like below, right after 2 tables in a page.

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[with=350mm, bb=0 0 1350 743]{path/to/figure.png}
\caption{Caption for it}
\label{label for it}
\end{figure}
```

This surely inserts the figure into the document in a new page, but is placed at the bottom of the page, and I am trying to put it on the top or at least the center of the page, since it would be the last page of a chapter. But the [htbp] settings are not working at all. What should I do to deal with this figure?

Update:
I made a minimal working example and paste it here. I am not using the package of float actually because it is not working for me, but I put it in this example.

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\chapter{EXPERIMENTS}
In this chapter the results for the tests and experiments are presented.

...for words before this figure.

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[bb=0 0 1166 693, width=30cm]{figs/result3.png}
\caption{Result for Matrix Multiplications: Time for Multiplication and Data Transfer}
\label{result3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And the figure result3.png is 1166 by 693 with 19.4KB. 
Is there anyone can tell me why this figure keeps staying at the bottom of the page please?

Comment: Thanks Thomas but it does not work for me. I have googled around for answers and neither the [htbp] nor the float package with [H] works for me. That is why I am here asking question...

Comment: Figure placement relies heavily on what else is going on in your document, including what the actual float contains. So it's difficult to say what you can do. You should create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the problem and allows the community to copy-and-paste and compile to see what your problem is.

Comment: Werner thank you for your link, I have made one but the community requires 5 reputation for asking a question, but my documents deadline is tomorrow. Should I ask it here?